# Formatting local storage items onto a jdPDF document correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

So I'm trying to take localStorage items and output it onto a PDF document which makes use of the jsPDF library with the aim of making an invoice of a users shopping cart. At the moment i can print the item names however they get smushed ontop of one another, and furthermore the price output is working incorrectly. I've shown this in the screenshot below. It seems to also output the text "PRICE" as the first element instead of 37.21

HTML

```
    <a id="itemName" class ="itemName">[ITEM_NAME]</a>

    <div class="item-price" id="itemPrice">[ITEM_PRICE] </div>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit1', function() {
        var itemToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("itemName");
        var itemPrices = document.getElementsByClassName("item-price");
        var itemName;
        var itemPrice;
        localStorage.setItem("itemToStore", JSON.stringify(itemToStore));
        localStorage.setItem("itemPrices", JSON.stringify(itemPrices));
        for (var i = 0; i < itemToStore.length; i++) {
            itemName = i temToStore[i].innerText;
            itemPrice = i temPrices[i].innerText;
            console.log("Item: " + itemName + itemPrice);
        }
        var pdf = n ew jsPDF(
            'p', 'pt', 'a4'); // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped. 



  for (var i=0 ; i < itemToStore .length; i++) { itemName=itemToStore [i].innerText; pdf.text(10,10, `Name` + itemName + itemPrice);
        }
pdf.save('Test.pdf');
});
```

Output of the PDF

[image: screenshot of the pdf]

Output of the console.log

[image: console.log output]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable to print in a better way your data, example from the site:

```
var columns = [
    {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
    {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
    {title: "Country", dataKey: "country"}, 
    ...
];
var rows = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Shaw", "country": "Tanzania", ...},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Nelson", "country": "Kazakhstan", ...},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Garcia", "country": "Madagascar", ...},
    ...
];

// Only pt supported (not mm or in)
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
    styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
    columnStyles: {
        id: {fillColor: 255}
    },
    margin: {top: 60},
    addPageContent: function(data) {
        doc.text("Header", 40, 30);
    }
});
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

so, you can change your code like:

```
var columns = [
    {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
    {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
    {title: "Price", dataKey: "price"},
]
var rows = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "ObjectName", "price": "40", ...},
    {"id": 2, "name": "ObjectName2", "price": "50", ...},
];
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. My only reservation would be i'll never know what the users will buy so i can't hard code the row ids

Comment: I think you can do a function that generate your rows in a proper way, if some data are missing in the row, the plugin just don't show anything in that particular column row, so you can have empty data in your object